# rgl segments3d to connect 3d scatter points in order to plot a skeleton

Tags: r, rgl

I am working with motion capture data, and wish to plot two skeletons in 3D (motion capture data obtained from two different systems).

I have managed to plot and label the joints, but I can´t figure out how to connect the joints with lines.

A short explanation to the abreviations used in the sample dataset below:
RA and LA (Right and Left Ankle)
RK and LK (Right and Left Knee)
RH and LH (Right and Left Hip)
CG (Center of Gravity)

Simplified data set:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Joint = c("LA", "RA", "LK", "RK", "LH", "RH", "CG", "LA", "RA", "LK", "RK", "LH", "RH", "CG"),
  system = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  x = c(0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 5, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 5),
  y = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 20,20,20,20,20,20,20),
  z = c(0, 0, 20, 20, 40, 40, 50, 0, 0, 20, 20, 40, 40, 50))
```

My code so far to plot and label the joints from the two systems:

```
library(rgl)
with(df, plot3d(x, y, z, type="s", col = as.numeric(system)))
with(df, text3d(x, y, z, text = Joint, adj = 2))
```

Can you help me connect the joints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `segments3d` function to draw line segments.  It takes the usual
`x`, `y`, `z` coordinates, and joins pairs of points.  So you'll need to work out which joints are joined, and plot segments between those joints.
If the joints are always in the order you gave, it would go something like this:

```
segs <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7)
segments3d(df[segs, 3:5])
```

(This just does the `system` A segments.)

Edited to add:  In response to the first comment:  You will need to tell R that ankles connect to knees, etc, but you can do that.  For example:

```
segs <- c()
for (s in unique(df$system)) {
  seg <- with(df, c(which(system == s & Joint == "LA"),
                    which(system == s & Joint == "LK"))
  if (length(seg) == 2)
    segs <- c(segs, seg)
  seg <- with(df, c(which(system == s & Joint == "LK"),
                    which(system == s & Joint == "CG"))
  if (length(seg) == 2)
    segs <- c(segs, seg)

  # etc for the other side
}
segments3d(df[segs, 3:5])
```

This could all be compressed if you have the connections arranged in an R object somehow.  I'll leave that to you to work out.

Comment: Thank you - exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to achieve the same results by somehow referring to the values of the Joint variable? I am asking because I expect that I will encounter situations where the order of the joints will differ.